# INSERT into DB2 with a user defined type column

Tags: sql, db2, user-defined-types

Hi i am trying to explore DB2 with user defined types I have created a type and a table but i am unable to insert the data into table now. My user defined type in DB is as follows:

```
CREATE TYPE pizza AS
(type varchar(50),
size INTEGER,
topping varchar(50))
MODE DB2SQL@
```

Then i have created a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE orders
(id  INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
customer VARCHAR(50),
pizza_row pizza)@
```

Then when i try to insert i got error here is my insert statement:

```
INSERT into orders (id,customer,pizza_row) 
VALUES (1,'Larry', pizza('margarita',10,'kebab'))@
```

Error received:

> No authorized routine named "PIZZA" of type "FUNCTION" having
>   compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440

What is the correct syntax of inserting into my schema?

Comment: Shouldn't strings be wrapped with a single quote mark `'` ?

Comment: @sagi correct sorry let me edit

Comment: And still same error ?

Comment: Nah now its changed it `No authorized routine named "pizza" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440`

Comment: of course i don't have any routine name `pizza` then question comes how can i insert in the UDT column without writing any routine/function

Comment: ANSI SQL: `... VALUES (1,'Larry', new pizza('margarita',10,'kebab'))`.

Comment: @jarlh its not working giving me unexpected token `pizza` error with `SQLCODE=-104`

Comment: How about you start your exploration with one primitive For example smallint for size of pizza?  It looks like you'll need a function that returns your custom type for what you are currently doing.   Good Luck

Comment: @danny117 actually i have already started working on a sample case that i have already posted. Thing is not about how many primitives there are actual problem is why even with more than one i am having this problem. I mean even i am not getting any syntax error from the compiler. Thanks btw :)

Comment: The [default constructor function has no parameters](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_10.5.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000933.html?cp=SSEPGG_10.5.0%2F2-12-7-112&lang=en): `pizza()`. If you want to instantiate your type with some values, you'll need to create your own constructor function.

Comment: @mustaccio thanks mate that was helping one.

Comment: I see someone posted a function for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default constructor function, which DB2 generates automatically when a structured type is created, has no parameters: `pizza()`. If you want to instantiate your type with some values, you'll need to create your own constructor function that would call the default constructor, then assign appropriate values to the type's fields, something along these lines:

```
create or replace function pizza (
 p_type varchar(50),
 p_size INTEGER,
 p_topping varchar(50)
)
returns pizza
begin atomic
  declare t pizza;
  set t = pizza();
  set t..type = p_type;
  set t..size = p_size;
  set t..topping = p_topping;
  return t;
end
```

PS. Code not tested.

Comment: This is correct as well i did the same after your previous comment and it was working :)

Answer (score 1):

In IBM DB2 to insert and retrieve values you can use MUTATORS and OBSERVERS.

When you create a structured type, DB2 automatically generates a constructor method for the type, and generates mutator and observer methods for the attributes of the type. You can use these methods to create instances of structured types and to insert these instances into a column of a table.

Refer: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.structypes.doc/doc/t0006627.html

### INSERT

INSERT INTO orders VALUES
(1, 'Larry', pizza()..type('margarita')..size(10)..topping('mushrooms'))@

### SELECT

SELECT id, customer, pizza..type AS type, pizza..size AS size, pizza..topping AS topping FROM orders@