# Insert data into a column with user defined datatype in DB2

Tags: insert, db2, sql-insert, user-defined-data-types

I created a user defined datatype using the following query

```
CREATE TYPE test3.data_type1 AS
(xmldata clob(204800) logged NOT compact)
INSTANTIABLE
inline LENGTH 195
MODE DB2SQL;
```

I then created a table using the following query:

```
CREATE TABLE test3.test_table
(col1 varchar(256),
col2 test3.data_type1,
col3 varchar(254),
col4 varchar(128),
col5 varchar(128) WITH DEFAULT USER,
col6 timestamp WITH DEFAULT,
col7 varchar(128),
col8 timestamp)
;
```

I am now trying to insert data into this table, test_table using:

```
INSERT INTO test3.test_table (col2)
VALUES
(data_type1('aaaa'));
```

The error I get is as follows:

```
SQL Error [42884]: No authorized routine named "DATA_TYPE1" of type "FUNCTION" having compatible arguments was found.. SQLCODE=-440, SQLSTATE=42884, DRIVER=4.26.14
```

I also tried multiple options of this insert statement but with no luck. I also tried creating a function as mentioned in this post [INSERT into DB2 with a user defined type column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37461096/insert-into-db2-with-a-user-defined-type-column)
But, I get an error while creating this function as well. Here is the function as per this post :

```
CREATE FUNCTION data_type1 (xmldata clob(204800)) 
RETURNS data_type1
BEGIN ATOMIC 
    DECLARE t data_type1;
    SET t = data_type1();
    SET t..xmldata = xmldata;
    RETURN t;
END
```

The error I get with this is as follows:

```
SQL Error [42704]: "DATA_TYPE1" is an undefined name.. SQLCODE=-204, SQLSTATE=42704, DRIVER=4.26.14
```

DB2 version - 11.5 LUW
Any pointers in the right direction would help.

Comment: You must additionally transform functions with `create transform for ...` usually as a pair, one with `FROM SQL` other with `TO SQL`. One can use your existing udf. See docs.

Comment: @mao , I cannot create the function in itself, I get an error

Comment: there are some restrictions on returns datatypes for sql scalar functions, one is that the returned type cannot be based on a large object (and yours is). That would give SQL0789N.   Never write "get an error", always instead write the exact full error text and error code. Also edit your question to add the Db2-platform (z/os,  i-series, luw) and Db2-version.